# What is the best practice for creating MongoDB connections on python?

Tags: python, mongodb, database-connection, connection-string, connection-pooling

I store a large amount of time series data into MongoDB. For this purpose I use multiprocessing in python. I have also written several queries on these data.
For inserting data into MongoDB and also for each query, I used a separate MongoDB connection like this:

```
db_client = MongoClient(self.service_name, self.port_number)
```

However, another solution is to define MongoClient one time as a global variable and using it in different functions.
What is the best way to creating mongo connection in python for different functions and classes?
Thanks